# How can I skip execution of methods based on class instance attribute?

Tags: python, oop

In this program, I am supposed to store it in the same location as another file (main.py) and run that file to test the code.

I am running into an issue when I power off the TV, the volume and channels shouldn't change, yet they do.

An 'if' statement should go somewhere, maybe in the power function? But I just can't figure out how to go about it.

```
class Television:
min_volume = 0
max_volume = 2
min_channel = 0
max_channel = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = False
        self.muted = False
        self.volume = Television.min_volume
        self.channel = Television.min_channel

    def power(self):
        self.status = not self.status


    def mute(self):
        self.muted = not self.muted

    def channel_up(self):
        self.channel += 1
        if self.channel > Television.max_channel:
            self.channel = Television.min_channel

    def channel_down(self):
        self.channel -= 1
        if self.channel < Television.min_channel:
            self.channel = Television.max_channel

    def volume_up(self):
        self.volume += 1
        if self.volume > Television.max_volume:
            self.volume = Television.max_volume

    def volume_down(self):
        self.volume -= 1
        if self.volume < Television.min_volume:
            self.volume = Television.min_volume

    def __str__(self):
        Power = "True" if self.status else "False"
        return f"TV Status: Power = {self.status}, Channel = {self.channel}, Volume = {self.volume}"
```

Comment: Please try to write your question in a way that will apply to people encountering the same programming problem in the context of writing a different piece of software (something that _isn't_ a TV state modeler).

Comment: Anyhow, you don't check `self.status` in `self.volume_up()` and `self.volume_down()`, so why do you expect them to change their behavior based on it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper that does the check, then you don't have to muck about with each function.

```py
class Television:
    min_volume = 0
    max_volume = 2
    min_channel = 0
    max_channel = 3

    def power_check(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.status:
                print("Powered off")
                return
            print("Powered on")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = False
        self.muted = False
        self.volume = Television.min_volume
        self.channel = Television.min_channel

    def power(self):
        self.status = not self.status

    @power_check
    def mute(self):
        self.muted = not self.muted

    @power_check
    def channel_up(self):
        self.channel += 1
        if self.channel > Television.max_channel:
            self.channel = Television.min_channel

    @power_check
    def channel_down(self):
        self.channel -= 1
        if self.channel < Television.min_channel:
            self.channel = Television.max_channel

    @power_check
    def volume_up(self):
        self.volume += 1
        if self.volume > Television.max_volume:
            self.volume = Television.max_volume

foo = Television()
foo.channel_up()
foo.power()
foo.channel_up()
```

that should result in something like:

```
Powered off
Powered on
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper for each method that requires power. This wrapper makes the method execute if the TV is on and does nothing if it is off.

Add this function *before* your class definition and add it as decorator to each class method you only want to execute when the TV is powered:

```py
def requires_power(func):
    """Executes method if Televison.status = True and does nothing if it is False."""
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        tv = args[0]
        if not tv.status:
            return None
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap


class Television:
    min_volume = 0
    max_volume = 2
    min_channel = 0
    max_channel = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.status = False
        self.muted = False
        self.volume = Television.min_volume
        self.channel = Television.min_channel

    def power(self):
        self.status = not self.status

    @requires_power
    def mute(self):
        self.muted = not self.muted

    @requires_power
    def channel_up(self):
        self.channel += 1
        if self.channel > Television.max_channel:
            self.channel = Television.min_channel

    @requires_power
    def channel_down(self):
        self.channel -= 1
        if self.channel < Television.min_channel:
            self.channel = Television.max_channel

    @requires_power
    def volume_up(self):
        self.volume += 1
        if self.volume > Television.max_volume:
            self.volume = Television.max_volume

    @requires_power
    def volume_down(self):
        self.volume -= 1
        if self.volume < Television.min_volume:
            self.volume = Television.min_volume

    def __str__(self):
        return f"TV Status: Power = {self.status}, Channel = {self.channel}, Volume = {self.volume}"
```

Test:

```py
tv = Television()
print(tv)
tv.power()
print(tv)
tv.volume_up()
print(tv)
tv.power()
tv.volume_up()
print(tv)
```

```
TV Status: Power = False, Channel = 0, Volume = 0
TV Status: Power = True, Channel = 0, Volume = 0
TV Status: Power = True, Channel = 0, Volume = 1
TV Status: Power = False, Channel = 0, Volume = 1
```